# ajax loading icon not showing in IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some reason, the loading/spinner icon won't show up in IE but works just fine in Firefox. Do you see anything wrong in my code?

My jQuery -

```
  var loader = $('#loading');

        loader.hide()
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                loader.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                loader.hide();
            });
```

My HTML looks something like this -

```
 <div id="te">
        ......
        <div id="container">
            ......
            <div id="body-container">
                ......
                <div id="loading">
                    <img alt="Loading, please wait.." src="/images/spinner.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my CSS -

```
#te #loading img { background: url('/images/spinner.gif') no-repeat; }
#te #loading  { background-color: #F9F9F9; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 5px; left: 45%;top: 45%; padding: 20px 50px; position: fixed; }
```

Update #1:
Have tried removing `#te #loading img` altogether from the css and modified `#te #loading` to this but it didn't work -

```
#te #loading  { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #F9F9F9; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 5px; left: 45%;top: 45%; padding: 20px 50px; position: fixed; z-index: 1000; }
```

Update #2:
Here's my js code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var cpdata;
        setupEvents();
        loadInitialData();

        function setupEvents() {
            var loader = $('#loading');
            loader.hide()
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                loader.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                loader.hide();
            });
            // some other stuff..
        }
        function loadInitialData() {
            cpdata = callMethod(urlLoadInitialData, {}, false);
            if (cpdata != null) {
                // do something with cpdata
            }
        }
        function callMethod(url, parameters, async) {
            var data;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
                async: async,
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    data = result.d;
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
    });</script>
```

Comment: try position:absolute for #te #loading

Comment: @Yorgo: I have tried that already. Still doesn't work.

Comment: your js code looks fine. I think loader displays but it shown under some other elements like div. Set the z-indexes

Comment: is it valid to specify a background-image on an img tag?

Comment: @ob - I saw that also, probably overkill to have both the img tag and the background - likely best to put the background image on the div and remove the img tag altogether.

Comment: I've removed the background image on the img. Please see my update.

Comment: @enigma - I want to see your ajax call code please.  I almost seems that ajaxStop fires prematurely OR a beforeSend returns false (which would fire the ajaxStop at the time)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I've updated the post with ajax call code. Please take a look.

Comment: I put another example - not all changes focused on this issue fully.(converters) but places the stop on the loading element.  Any errors would be interesting to have (including abort)

Comment: I answered something similar on this thread : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673849/css-ie-version-of-style-background-colorrgba/15541993#15541993) this worked for me so might help

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code slightly:

```
var loader = $('#loading');
loader.hide();
$.ajaxStart(function() {
    loader.show();
});
$.ajaxStop(function() {
    loader.hide();
});
```

Alternate:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
    jQuery.ajaxStart(function() {
        jQuery('#loading').show();
    });
    jQuery.ajaxStop(function() {
        jQuery('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Another alternate: use complete:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
    jQuery.ajaxStart(function() {
        jQuery('#loading').show();
    });
    jQuery.ajaxComplete(function() {
        jQuery('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

be sure to include:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

for the border radius in the css

One more attempt - likely no change but...

```
$(function() {
    var cpdata;
    var loader = $('#loading');
    loader.hide().ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    setupEvents();
    loadInitialData();

    function setupEvents() {
        // some other stuff..  
    }

    function loadInitialData() {
        cpdata = callMethod(urlLoadInitialData, {}, false);
        if (cpdata != null) { // do something with cpdata     
        }
    }

    function callMethod(url, parameters, async) {
        var returnData;
        var pString = JSON.stringify(parameters);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: pString,
            async: async,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            converters: {
                "json jsond": function(msg) {
                    return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
                }
            },
            success: function(result) {
                returnData = result;
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status;

                if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                }
                if (errorThrown == "abort") {
                    alert("Aborted Ajax");
                }
            }
        });
        return returnData;
    }
});
```

Comment: No dice. I've placed alerts before loader.show/hide and they come up just fine. But the loader won't show.

Comment: I make the assumption you put this code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){});` call

Comment: Actually in `$(function () { });` which is essentially the same as `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Comment: My guess is IE is doing something stupid with the fixed position and misinterpreting this and placing it off screen, or under something. Have you inspected the element behaviour with Firebug?

Comment: @JamieHartnoll: I removed the `loader.hide();` in the `$.ajaxStop` function and I can see the loader perfectly in the middle of the screen in IE. As soon as I add `loader.hide();` back in, it won't show up. Have also tried removing the fixed position. Nothing changed.

Comment: you MIGHT have to put the .hide inside the success: function. (assumption of only one ajax call in place/action with all this)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There are actually multiple ajax calls. I tried putting it one of the success functions but it _still_ doesn't show up. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: @enigma - if this last example as-is does not help, it is quite likely some OTHER jQuery ajax call is issuing the ajaxStop() in some way.(see my other note)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Thanks for the help. The issue was with `async:false` in the ajax call. It is locking up the browser.